# Ubuntu 20.04 can't boot from flash pendrive

Tags: boot, live-usb, 20.04

I did create a flash media to install Ubuntu 20.04 but it isn't booting. It reach the grub menu but stuck into a black screen.

I tried the same pendrive with an image of Ubuntu 19.10 and there weren't any problem for boot and install the distro. I tried eith an other pendrive as well.

Any clue of what I can do?

Comment: 20.04 was released today, so is on topic.  Do you have Nvidia video hardware?  May be the nomodeset is needed.

Comment: Yes, I have Nvidia video card. I will try nomodeset Thanks.

Comment: I tried with nomodeset, no changes...

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04 are booting normally from pendrive.

Comment: I disabled PPT from BIOS and this allow me to boot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After disable the PPT configuration from BIOS I was allowed to boot from the flash memory stick and finished the installation process.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 7460.
Intel Core i5-7200U CPU.
NVidia GeForce 940MX (driver Nouveau).

Comment: i don't have PPT option in the boot menu dell xps 15

Answer (score 2):

(For the other people who jump in this thread from Google.)

I experienced the same problem on my Dell Precision 3540 Developer Edition (w/ Intel i7-8565U). I was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 but also stuck after the grub menu.

I googled the problem and found that several people resolved this problem by enabling legacy boot or turning of PPT configuration in BIOS. In my case, I had no configurable option in PPT and the `Secure Boot > Secure Boot Enable` option was OFF by default.

So I changed the `Secure Boot > Secure Boot Mode` option into Audit Mode and solved the problem.

And now It works like a charm. Hope this post helps.

Comment: Note: as of Linux version 5.4.0-33-generic, this problem seems fixed.